# Why can't I see the settings for the customfilter module in the Drupal admin?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/210551) to add a custom filter using the [Custom Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter) module. I've installed and enabled the module.

However, when I try to navigate to `/admin/settings/filters` like it suggests, there is nothing there nor can I see any settings for the Custom Filter module anywhere in the admin interface.

What do I need to do to get this module working?

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to navigate to /admin/settings/filters like it suggests

I'm not sure where you've seen that, but looking at the code, it's wrong. Maybe you're following a tutorial for a previous version of Drupal.

Either way, the config path for the D7 version is **admin/settings/customfilter**.